# Finite set of generators of monomial ideal form Gröbner basis

Tags: abstract-algebra, commutative-algebra, groebner-basis, monomial-ideals

Given a set of monomials $\{G_1,\ldots,G_t\}$ generating a non-null monomial ideal $I \le K[X_1,\ldots,K_n]$ I would like to check that they form a Gröbner basis.

This is done by Buchberger's algorithm by computing semizygies $S(X^\alpha,X^\beta) = X^{\max{\alpha,\beta}-\alpha} X^\alpha - X^{\max{\alpha,\beta}-\beta}X^\beta = 0$. The problem is that then I should compute $R(0;G)$ the remainder of zero by polynomial division by the elements of $G$. However the polynomial division that I know is not defined for zero.

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: If you get $0$ for the (semi)syzygy, then the remainder is $0$.  In general, if $I$ is generated by monomials $\{G_1,\dots,G_t\}$, then $\{G_1,\dots,G_t\}$ form a Groebner basis - it's easy to see that for any $f\in I$, some monomial divides the leading term of $f$.

Comment: @MichaelBurr with the standard division algorithm you mean? in principle unicity properties of remainder and quotient are not guaranteed

Comment: I mean with the multivariate division algorithm.  In general, at each step of the multivariate division algorithm, you keep decreasing (according to the fixed monomial order) the monomials that appear in $f$ (really $f-g$, where $g\in I$).  $0$ has no monomials to decrease, so the division algorithm does nothing to $0$.  Thus, the remainder is $0$.  In general the remainder does not need to be unique, but not in the case of $0$.

Comment: @MichaelBurr it seems that you're right, Buchberger criterion works with the general division algorithm without imposing uniqueness on remainders and quotients (they're the ones given by the algorithm), my formulation required $f \neq 0$.

Comment: If $f=0$, then the algorithm terminates right away.  So, you likely assumed that $f\not=0$ so that there was something to do.  Anyway, it's easier to prove that the $G_i$'s form a Groenber basis through the definition of a Groebner basis than via the algorithm.